# registrar si existe en la base de datos

Tags: php

hola buenas este es mi codigo. todo va bien no tengo errores pero quisiera que me apareciera un  mensaje si la cedula no existe y por lo tanto no me dejara registrar el formulario. si existe la cedula me permira registrar la informacion . esto es con el fin de que solo los usuarios puedan registrar pagos. si hay una persona que no esta registrada previamente no podra hacer un registro . gracias de antemano.

```
<?php
    $nombre = $conn->escape_string($_POST['nombre']);
    $apellido = $conn->escape_string($_POST['apellido']);
    $email = $conn->escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $cedula = $conn->escape_string($_POST['cedula']);
    $telefono = $conn->escape_string($_POST['telefono']);
    $banco = $conn->escape_string($_POST['banco']);
    $fecha = $conn->escape_string($_POST['fecha']);
    $hora = $conn->escape_string($_POST['hora']);
    $referencia = $conn->escape_string($_POST['referencia']);
    $monto = $conn->escape_string($_POST['monto']);

   // uso esto pero creo que tengo que hacer que en ves de que me de error, que me de permiso para hacer el registro 
   //y si no aparece la cedula en la tabla (rm_user) le de un mensaje que diga ( el numero de cedula no esta registrado )
    $resultEmail = $conn->query("SELECT 1 FROM rm_users WHERE username = '$username'") or die($conn->error());
    if($resultEmail->num_rows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'El numero de cedula no esta registrado';
    }

      $resultEmail = $conn->query("SELECT 1 FROM pagos_pagina WHERE referencia = '$referencia'") or die($conn->error());
      if($resultEmail->num_rows > 0) {
          $_SESSION['message'] = 'El numero de referencia ya existe';
      }else {

            $sql = 
                "INSERT INTO pagos_pagina (
                    nombre, 
                    apellido, 
                    email, 
                    cedula, 
                    telefono,
                    banco,
                    fecha,
                    hora,
                    referencia,
                    monto
                    ) 
                    "."
                    VALUES (
                        '$nombre',
                        '$apellido',
                        '$email',
                        '$cedula',
                        '$telefono',
                        '$banco',
                        '$fecha',
                        '$hora',
                        '$referencia',
                        '$monto'
                )";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Su pago a sido registrado correctamente ';
                } else {
                    // Devuelve un mensaje de error
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Ocurrio un error al Registrar su Pago';
            }
        }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que bastaría en hacer una consulta por cédula en la tabla donde este el dato, algo parecido a lo que haces en:

```
$resultEmail = $conn->query("SELECT 1 FROM pagos_pagina WHERE referencia = '$referencia'") or die($conn->error());
  if($resultEmail->num_rows > 0) {
      $_SESSION['message'] = 'El numero de referencia ya existe';
```

Pero cambiando el operador a que si es 0 significa que no esta registrado.

Comment: exactamente pero no logro hacer que eso pase no se si cambiando el parametro de ese codigo o falta mas codigo de verdad no se

Comment: puedes enviar donde esta el campo cédula y te lo escribo, pero veraz que la idea es la misma.

Comment: este es el codigo

Comment: <!--Cedula-->
      <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
       <label for="cedula">Cedula del Propietario</label>
       <input type="text" name="cedula" id="cedula" id="username" name="username"  placeholder="Cedula" required/>
      </div>

Comment: gracias muchas gracias por sus ayuda de antemano

Comment: con el valor de la cédula haces una consulta a la tabla donde este el campo, es que me enviaste el campo en el formulario y estaba preguntando la tabla donde lo guardas. Pero es lo que cité, en mi respuesta consultado por cédula y luego preguntas si las num_rows es igual a 0, si lo es pues retornas el error.

Comment: es tal cual lo que cito en mi respuesta.